# Android Design Support Library does not compile

Tags: android, compilation, implementation

https://gist.github.com/koraytem/89338cddbd50442164aeb555393a0d09  guys here is the link of my gradle page. When I add android design support library compile, it gives me this error

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html `.
>   Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Gradle plugin 3.0.0 onwards new configuration dependencies have been introduced. For more information please check **Use the new dependency configurations** at this [official link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration).

As you can see in the warning message, `compile` is obsolete and `implementation` need to be used. So need to make below changes:

**Current is:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

**Change to:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```